# Populating DataGribCombobox Columns using Static Resource key ( CollectionViewSource )

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am new to WPF. 
I have datagrid with two combobox columns. I want to populate one column with Employee Names and other column with product Names. Note : Employee Names are retrived from Entity framework object Employees and similary Product Names are retrueved from entity framework object Products.

Below is the code which does not work. I am not sure how to set the Datagrid itemsource because each comobobox columns are getting data from different static resouces ? Help would be greatly appricated.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="EmployeeLookup" Source="{Binding Path=EmpList}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ProdutsLookup" Source="{Binding Path=ProdList}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="203" HorizontalAlignment="Left"     Margin="22,92,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="416">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Employee"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source=   {StaticResource EmployeeLookup}}" DisplayMemberPath="FirstName"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Products"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProdutsLookup}}" DisplayMemberPath="ProductName"/>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Why you are using DataGrid? If you don't have a collection for datagrid then how the datagrid will get populate with drop down.

Comment: How can i set the datagrid ItemSource to a property which contains data for both the combobox columns.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Normaly, DataGrid is used when you already have a source for it, and you fill comboboxes with different source to give the user available values for the combobox columns. Can you show (draw) what kind of result you expect?

Comment: You have answered my question but i am not clear on how to do it in code. How can i set datagrid with a source and fill comboboxes with different source.

Comment: Sorry dont have permission to attach image. Basically a datagrid used for entering Invoice data. So user will be presented with a datagrid with four columns.

Comment: Sorry dont have permission to attach image. Basically datagrid is used for generating Invoice. So user will be presented with a datagrid with four columns and rows should increment as user enters the items on each row. Four columns are 1) Combobox (dropdownlist) asking user to select and employee 2)Combobox (dropdownlist) asking user to slect an product 3) a text box asking user to enter Quantity 4) Text box asking user to enter Amount. When user finishes entering the first row the second row should again have first two comobobox columns poulated again for entering data.